# how to carry over the sequence number from one table to another?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create 2 tables, and I want to create a common Sequence ID for both tables.  Sequnce ID should not be duplicated in both tables.  I am trying to create using Identity, but I dont know how to carry over the maximum id from Table 1 to Table 2.

I am using MS SQL server 2008.

I want those 2 tables similar to below,

**Table 1:**

```
Seq_ID    value1 value2

1           x     y

2           a     b
```

**Table 2:**

```
Seq_ID    value1 value2

  3        i      j

  4        k      l
```

Comment: Why do you need this?  This reads like a data design problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

Identity cannot innately be used across tables for a single identity.

"carry over the maximum id from Table 1 to Table 2." this would lead me to believe that you assume the data in table 1 would never change for the table 2 identity to start at the max table 1?

If you know the data will never change then just set up the data in table 1, and set an identity in table 2 with a start value of the maxId from table 1 + 1

```
-- create table1
-- insert data into table1
declare @maxId int
select @maxId = max(id) + 1
from table1

create table table2 (id int primary key identity(@maxId,1)
```

Another option would be to stagger the IDs between the tables so there will never be overlap:

```
create table table1 (id int primary key identity(1,2))
create table table2 (id int primary key identity(2,2))
```

`table1` will always have an odd ID, `table2` will always have an even.  In this method however, `table2`s IDs will not necessarily be greater than the max id from `table1`.

EDIT:  if you needed `table1` IDs to always be greater than `table2` you could also do this:

```
create table table1 (id int primary key identity(0,-1))
create table table2 (id int primary key identity(1,1))
```

`table1` will start with 0 and go backwards (0,-1,-2), `table2` will start at 1 and go up (1,2,3).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't The [sequence object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ff878091(v=sql.120).aspx) work for you ? I think is the best solution in this case, you need to try it.

Regards!

Comment: note OP specified SQL server 2008, `sequence` is not available until 2012

Answer (score 0):

**In the absence of [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)**, you can "hack" it by having a Sequence table with an identity column. But this means you have to insert into two tables. First insert into the "sequence" table to get the new id, then use that value in the child tables.

Other option is to create a function GetMaxId value and add 1. However, be careful when you do this. You'll need the tables locked to prevent concurrent access while you're performing this operation. May want to insert a placeholder record with a new id before doing rest of your logic to minimize your lock duration.

The first option is better. Better yet, **UPGRADE TO SQL SERVER 2012!**

Actually, I don't know if this will work for you but there's on more option. Make Table1 Id `identity (1,1)` and the other `identity(-1,-1)`

You can try it out with this..

```
CREATE TABLE #x (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), b BIT)
CREATE TABLE #y (id INT IDENTITY(-1,-1), b BIT)

INSERT INTO #x VALUES (1),(1),(1)
INSERT INTO #y VALUES (1),(1),(1)

SELECT * FROM #x
SELECT * FROM #y
```

I don't think I have to mention this is not a scale-able solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two identical tables with same column names and same data type that need to share an identiy smells like a data design problem to me.

But you could just have one table

Table:

```
Seq_ID  TableID    value1 value2

1       1          x      y   
2       1          a      b    
3       2          i      j
4       2          k      l
```